Swagger schema not generating securitySchemes under components
I am generating openAPI schema but it is not generating securitySchemes eventhough I added relevent code in my spring boot application.
As you can see below, the JSON section under compoments is not having securitySchemes section.

Below is some of my code snippet
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency> 
        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
@Profile({"dev", "localhost"})
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    
    private String accessTokenUri = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token";
     @Bean
      public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("myapi.demo.controller"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(metaData())
            .protocols(protocols())
            .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securitySchemes()))
            .securityContexts(securityContexts());
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfo(
            "demo API",
            "The demo endpoint returns information about the my sample Api.",
            "1.0",
            "",
            new Contact("DEV", "", "Dev@abc.com"),
            "DEV",
            "",  new ArrayList<VendorExtension>());
      }
      
        private Set<String> protocols() {
            Set<String> protocols = new HashSet<>();
            protocols.add("http");
            return protocols;
        }
                
        private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {

            final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = { new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all") };

            return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("oauth2", authorizationScopes));
        }
        
        private List<SecurityContext> securityContexts() {
            List<SecurityContext> securityContexts   = Arrays.asList(SecurityContext.builder().forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build());
            return securityContexts;
        }
        
        private List<SecurityReference> securityReferences() {
            AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
            = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Lists.newArrayList(
            new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
        }
        
        private OAuth securitySchemes() {

            List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList<>();
            authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));

            List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<>();
            GrantType passwordCredentialsGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(accessTokenUri);

            grantTypes.add(passwordCredentialsGrant);

            return new OAuth("oauth2", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);

        }



@SecurityScheme(
        type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2
    )
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",allowedHeaders = "*")
public class MyDemoController {

The expectation is that I need the securitySchemes generated in the swagger schema with the relevent OAuth2 details in it like below.

Please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks in advance!

I think I am using swagger 2 dependencies, but I need to use openAPI to generate 3 version. Kindly help with some code sample like in github, thanks!

Correct first you have to upgrade Swagger 2 to OpenApi 3, you can refer this link Upgrade OpenAPI Another link.
